# Scheduled task doesn't seem to work

Tags: windows-xp, backup, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to back up all the data from a cash register system every morning. I don't know if the user I'm running the task as will be logged in and I discovered that Windows XP doesn't actually mount the Z drive (Windows share) until after I actually need it. The scheduled task runs a bat script which tries to mount the shared drive first (the first 2 lines of code) after which it performs the backup. I can see in my scheduled tasks list that the task is run according to the schedule, but it seems that something happens with the backup process.

If I run the task manually the backup program's GUI comes up and everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    net use z: /delete
net use z: \\server\z /USER:192.168.1.108\user pass
C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntbackup.exe backup "@C:\Documents and Settings\kasse\Lokale indstillinger\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows NT\NTBackup\data\pos backup.bks" /a /d "Kopis?t oprettet d. 18-05-2012 kl. 11:35" /v:yes /r:no /rs:no /hc:off /m normal /j "pos backup" /l:s /f "Z:\IT\kasse backups\Backup.bkf"
```